HTML/PHP form suddenly stopped working without changing code
I have a website which displays a directory/folders where I can upload multiple files onto said directory/folder to easily access important documents/articles. It's been working beautifully for about a year and suddenly stopped working the last month. I know that I have not changed my code accidentally because I have several folders with the same php file copy/pasted into each folder and would be impossible for me to have changed each php file.
What's weird is that if I try uploading 1 file at a time, it fails and uploads a 0 byte document. If I upload multiple files, the first file fails & uploads a 0 byte document, but all subsequent files are able to upload successfully.
I don't know if something changed with my hosting provider or something changed with input type=file usage but would love help. Thanks!!
screenshot of website format. first file attempted to upload listed as 0 bytes, second file able to upload
HTML
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload" multiple="multiple">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>

PHP
<?php
$targetDir = __DIR__ . '/'; // Directory where uploaded files will be stored

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
// Loop through each uploaded file
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]); $i++) {
    $targetFile = $targetDir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]); // Get the filename of the uploaded file

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($targetFile)) {
        echo '<script>alert("Sorry, the file '. basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]). ' already exists.");</script>';
        continue; // Skip to the next iteration of the loop
    }

    // Check file size (optional)
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"][$i] > 100000000) { // Adjust the file size limit as per your requirements
         echo '<script>alert("Sorry, your file '. basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]). ' is too large.");</script>';
        continue; // Skip to the next iteration of the loop
    }

    // If the upload is successful, move the uploaded file to the target directory
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i], $targetFile)) {
        echo '<script>alert("The file '. basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]). ' has been uploaded.");</script>';
    } else {
        echo '<script>alert("Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.");</script>';
    }
}

// Redirect back to the upload page
$redirectUrl = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/') . '/list.php';
echo '<script>window.location.href = "'.$redirectUrl.'";</script>';
}
?>

I have tried several different computers (personal and public ones) on chrome, safari, phone brave app, and nothing works, so suspect it is code-related or server related.
I tried changing permissions (currently 0755), but no luck there.
I don't really know much about changing specifics of files/settings on hosting server... I did try to disable htaccess and re-enable, but that didn't do anything.

I have tested the code on my localhost and is working. The problem may be related to your server. Like a PHP version or something.

Thank you very much for confirming!! Any tips on things to check on my server settings? I’m using php version 7.3 which I think is my default

Try on your localhost. And try to implement the same setting on your server. Please check the php.ini for configurations like upload_max_filesize

Solved! Ended up inserting a delay at beginning of upload.php code to account for server lag, which resolved the issue.... Still not sure what changed on the server end though since code was fine for over a year...
<?php $targetDir = __DIR__ . '/'; 
// Directory where uploaded files will be stored
 
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    ***sleep(0.5);***

// Loop through each uploaded file 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["file 
...


It's difficult to help you without access to the server, but I'll try to give you a few pointers.

The problem may come from a corrupted pdf. The upload may fail even if you can open the file with a pdf reader. So the first thing to do is to test with other pdf files.

Check the php logs and the server's capacity. A file may be too large for the server to handle. You can increase the maximum size of uploaded files by modifying the PHP configuration (upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, etc.).

The problem may possibly be due to a change in the firewall configuration, although this is unlikely as some uploads get through and others don't.

Write a test file, the most basic as possible and check the posted data with var_dump($_POST), etc.


Hoping it might help.

Thanks for the suggestions! I don’t this it’s file dependent. For example if I upload 2 files at once, it’s always the first file that fails and second always works aka both files will upload if I just swap the order. The same occurs with multiple file formats like jpg and txt, similarly only the second file and beyond upload (I tried 10 uploads at once and all except first work).
Also don’t think it’s code dependent since I haven’t changed anything.
Regarding #2, where can I find php logs.  I agree it’s probably server related but not sure where to start on that topic. I use A2hosting

If you want to send me your server access (FTP + server manager) I can take a look, you can contact me from here: https://www.miglisoft.com/#contact

Thanks - how do I send that info over? I was able to find error logs. There's something going on with apache filescan.

[Sun Apr 14 23:51:2024] [security2:error] [pid 6233:tid ] [client :58756] [client ] ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "rx ^$" against "FILES_TMPNAMES:fileToUpload[]" required. [file "/etc/apache2/conf.d/modsec_vendor_configs/imunify360-full-apache/014_i360_filescan.conf"] [line "43"] [id "77317957"] [msg "IM360 WAF: Track file upload||MV:/tmp/||Size:266622||User:||SC:/home//upload.php||WPU:||T:APACHE||"] [severity "NOTICE"] [tag "service_im360"] [tag "noshow"] [hostname ".com"] [uri "//upload.php"] [unique_id ""], referer: https://list.php

ModSecurity detected a potential issue during a file upload. It's looking for a non-empty temporary file name associated with the uploaded file, but it might be empty or not following the expected format. This could be due to various reasons, such as:
A bug in the upload script (upload.php)
A misconfiguration in ModSecurity rules
A temporary glitch during the upload process
You should report this to your hosting service and ask them for help.

Omg fixed! Hosting server never replied but i ended up adding a tiny delay, which solved the issue.
    ***sleep(0.5);***


I'm glad you fixed it
